# tratando de obtener la propiedad de no objeto?

Tags: php, codeigniter

hola estoy intentando traer los valores de imagen de descripcion de la base de datos en codeigniter pero me sale: Intentando obtener la propiedad de un no objeto el error me da en

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Productos</h1>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?foreach($productos as $producto): ?>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">  

                <img src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$producto->imagen)?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?=$producto->nombre?>">


                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?=$producto->nombre?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><?=$producto->precio?> $</p>
                    <a href="<?=site_url('add' . $producto->id)?>" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endforeach;?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <?=$pagination?>
    </div>
</div>
```

en esta parte me da error

Answer (score 0):

En esta línea:

`<img src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$productos->imagen)?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?=$producto->nombre?>">`

Tienes que cambiar `$productos->imagen` por `$producto->imagen`.

El error te está diciendo que estás intentando acceder a una propiedad de un objeto en algo que no es un objeto. En este caso, `$productos` es un array.